# Query Entry where number field is conditional to value

Tags: craft3, entry, query

I am trying to get entries where a specific number field is bigger than the given value.

[image]

But Craft is giving me the following response: [image]

Am i missing something or is this not supported for number fields?

Greetings

Comment: You're using ``%s`` (string) for [``sprintf``](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). If you change it do ``%d`` does it work? Not sure you need sprintf in this case?

Comment: Does it work like this? `Entry::find()->generation_to("> ${year}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem had nothing to do with Craft. I simply handled the initial value that i got from the request wrong